# Rails function that searches for my link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making a tool for a website thats under contruction that makes linkbuilding easier. This site is written in Ruby On Rails. Now that i'm learning RoR, i don't know were to start to make a function that searches a external site, which URL has been saved, to check that my url exist on that particular site. If so => display, if not: set URL non-active

So my questions:

1. Can I search a site from my application?
2. What is the best way to do this?
3. How often would you make such a script run?

Comment: I think you need a HTML parser. I heard that Nokogiri is quite good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to verify a URL is active.

Answers to your questions:

1. Yes you can make HTTP requests to another URL.
2. For making HTTP requests look at the Nestful gem or you can use Net::HTTP from the standard lib.
3. You don't give clear information about your requirements, so it is hard to say what is right, but you could run the check when the author submits the form. If you worry about slow responses use delayed_job to make the check asynchronous.

Comment: I used the standard lib from library, thank you! Its finally working now.